# syntax error while running collection in node js

Tags: postman-newman

while running below code

```
const newman = require("newman");
newman.run(
    {
        collection: require("./test.postman_collection.JSON"),
        reporters: "cli",
    },
    function (err) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        console.log("collection run complete");
    }
);
```

though the collection is in proper json format still its throwing below error.

test.postman_collection.JSON:2
"info": {
^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the file was without extesion (.json). Adding the extension solved the error